# Python regex for finding contents of MediaWiki markup links

Tags: python, regex, mediawiki

If I have some xml containing things like the following mediawiki markup:

> "    ...collected in the 12th century, of which [[Alexander the Great]] was the
>   hero, and in which he was represented,
>   somewhat like the British [[King
>   Arthur|Arthur]]"

what would be the appropriate arguments to something like:

`re.findall([[__?__]], article_entry)`

I am stumbling a bit on escaping the double square brackets, and getting the proper link for text like: `[[Alexander of Paris|poet named Alexander]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"\[\[([\w \|]+)\]\]")
text = "blah blah [[Alexander of Paris|poet named Alexander]] bldfkas"
results = pattern.findall(text)

output = []
for link in results:
    output.append(link.split("|")[0])

# outputs ['Alexander of Paris']
```

Version 2, puts more into the regex, but as a result, changes the output:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"\[\[([\w ]+)(\|[\w ]+)?\]\]")
text = "[[a|b]] fdkjf [[c|d]] fjdsj [[efg]]"
results = pattern.findall(text)

# outputs [('a', '|b'), ('c', '|d'), ('efg', '')]

print [link[0] for link in results]

# outputs ['a', 'c', 'efg']
```

Version 3, if you only want the link without the title.

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\[\[([\w ]+)(?:\|[\w ]+)?\]\]")
text = "[[a|b]] fdkjf [[c|d]] fjdsj [[efg]]"
results = pattern.findall(text)

# outputs ['a', 'c', 'efg']
```

Comment: I am using `\[\[(.+?)\]\]` for my own purposes. It’s somewhat shorter. :)

Answer (score 1):

**RegExp:** \w+( \w+)+(?=]])

**input**

[[Alexander of Paris|poet named Alexander]]

**output**

poet named Alexander

**input**

[[Alexander of Paris]]

**output**

Alexander of Paris

Comment: This is not the wanted output. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"\[\[([\w ]+)(?:\||\]\])")
text = "of which [[Alexander the Great]] was somewhat like [[King Arthur|Arthur]]"
results = pattern.findall(text)
print results
```

Would give the output

```
["Alexander the Great", "King Arthur"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get all the links from a page, of course it is much easier to use the MediaWiki API if at all possible, e.g. [http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=links&titles=Stack_Overflow_(website)](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=links&titles=Stack_Overflow_%28website%29).

Note that both these methods miss links embedded in templates.