# Checking to have only One vertical bar | in a string ? using regex

Tags: java, regex

So I am having the [same example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809837/python-regex-for-finding-contents-of-mediawiki-markup-links) that is been asked, which is xml containing things like the following mediawiki markup:

> " ...collected in the 12th century, of which [[Alexander the Great]]
>   was the hero, and in which he was represented, somewhat like the
>   British [[King Arthur|Arthur]]"

using this regexp:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[\\[([\\w | \\w]+)\\]\\]");
```

**It is working fine** and I get this output:

```
Alexander the Great
King Arthur|Arthur
```

---

**The problem**: If I had a text like `[[Alexander|the |Great]]` with two  or many vertical bars,
this should not match but it matches.

So I changed my regex to match only one vertical bar but did not work:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[\\[([\\w |? \\w]+)\\]\\]");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find expressions inside `[[` and `]]` which contain alphanumeric characters, spaces and exactly one pipe you can use the following regex

```
\[\[[\w ]+[\|]{1}[\w ]+\]\]
```

This however accounts only for those cases in which pipe isn't the first or the last character, but assuming from your question, this situation shouldn't occur.

Comment: If you want one or none pipes change the curly braces to {0,1}

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[\\[([\\w ]+\\|?[\\w ]*)\\]\\]");
```

or, as in comments from @fge:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[\\[([\\w ]+(?:\\|[\\w ])?)\\]\\]");
```

Comment: Another solution would be (out of a Java string) `\[\[(\w+(?:|\w+)?\]\]`

Comment: Rohit. I tested your one but I got java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 12
\[\[([\w ]+|?[\w ]*)\]\]
            ^

Comment: @COLDICE Ah! You need to escape the `|`. I forgot it.